# ABC: Population Monte Carlo (PMC) vs Sequential Monte Carlo (SMC)?

Tags: bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo, approximate-bayesian-computation

I'm reading about the [Approximate Bayesian Computation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximate_Bayesian_computation) (ABC) method, and I came across two rather popular approaches:

- [Sequential Monte Carlo (SMC)](https://rss.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/j.1467-9868.2006.00553.x)

  > methodology to sample sequentially from a sequence of probability distributions that are defined on a common space, each distribution being known up to a normalizing constant.
- [Population Monte Carlo (PMC)](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1198/106186004X12803)

  > principle consists of iterated generations of importance samples, with importance functions depending on the previously generated importance samples.

Reading these descriptions, they don't look very similar. But I also came across an [entry in Xi'an's blog](https://xianblog.wordpress.com/tag/abc-pmc/) where these two approaches seem to be treated as the same thing:

> astroABC: ABC SMC sampler for cosmological parameter estimation: (...) The version of ABC implemented there is “our” ABC PMC...

Where, if I understand correctly, Xi'an writes about an ABC-SMC sampler that is an implementation of his ABC-PMC sampler.

So the question is: are these two approaches equivalent?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What I mean by this remark is that population Monte Carlo is sequential, in the sense that one constructs a weighted sample by importance sampling and utilises this sample to build a more efficient importance function for the following iteration. In the original ABC-PMC paper, we did not stress enough the fact that the target may change at each iteration, using for instance a decreasing sequence $\epsilon_t$ of tolerances.